# Windows 10 kills Store/system apps when moving them to a 2nd screen via Win+arrows. Why?

Tags: windows-10

On my **Windows 10 Pro (build 17134 - "creator's update"**-powered 2-in-1 laptop (not Surface, but alike) I often move around windows  by using **WIN + arrow keys**.

This leads Windows to **kill apps which were either pre-installed or installed from the Store** almost all the time, especially when I try to move the app to a **different screen** (I use my laptop's screen + an external one over hdmi).

To further clarify, by "kill" I mean the **apps simply close themselves** and I can see no instanced running in the task-or-tray bar in any of the screen in use.

**How can I troubleshoot/solve this issue**?

Comment: If you move them with your mouse does it still happen?

Comment: @Ramhound usually not

Comment: These all UWP applications?  Can you move the Settings application?  Creators Update 1703 you are nearly to the point where 1903 is being released.  You might want to consider 1803 or 1809 and see if they also have the problem.

Comment: @ramhound will surely check again the next update. yes, I think they're UWP. I just tried with Settings and another app which I know it crashes all the time (SoundCloud) and no issue. I've however noticed this happens mostly when I have many Chrome tabs and apps open. In spite of 16gb ram...

Comment: Chrome is a notorious memory hog.  If they are from the Windows Store, then they are UWP application.  I was asking if "all" UWP applications crashed, which you just indicated, was not the case since Settings does not crash.  So this is either unique to SoundCloud or releated to the fact you are still running on 1703.